# How to retain Azure Cosmos DB continuous token

Tags: python, cookies, pagination, header, azure-cosmosdb

Background: FastAPI + CosmosDB

The official pagination code example for the CosmosDB python SDK is show below. It only shown how to get the next page via continues token. There are multiple users for my API, token has to related to the users.

How can I save the token in the headers or cookies? And if that is possible, how can I get the previous token?

```
def test_paging_with_continuation_token(self):
created_collection = self.config.create_multi_partition_collection_with_custom_pk_if_not_exist(self.client)

document_definition = {'pk': 'pk', 'id': '1'}
created_collection.create_item(body=document_definition)
document_definition = {'pk': 'pk', 'id': '2'}
created_collection.create_item(body=document_definition)

query = 'SELECT * from c'
query_iterable = created_collection.query_items(
    query=query,
    partition_key='pk',
    max_item_count=1
)
pager = query_iterable.by_page()
pager.next()
token = pager.continuation_token
second_page = list(pager.next())[0]

pager = query_iterable.by_page(token)
second_page_fetched_with_continuation_token = list(pager.next())[0]

self.assertEqual(second_page['id'], second_page_fetched_with_continuation_token['id'])
```

Comment: Added how can I retain the token and how to get the previous token

Comment: In your code you're simply writing a test case. Can you provide the code where you're actually returning some value back to the user. BTW, there's no right or wrong approach here - you can return the token in cookies or headers (whatever works for you). In one of the projects I worked on, I returned the token in headers. I base64 encoded the token before returning.